# Finding the critical points of $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

> Finding the critical points of $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)$

I know that $(a,b)$ is a critical point $\iff \nabla f(a,b)=(0,0)$

So $\nabla f(x,y)= (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$

- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}[(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)]=8x^3-6xy$
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}[(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)]=-3x^2+2y$

$\nabla f(x,y)=(8x^3-6xy, -3x^2+2y)=(0,0) \iff (x,y)=(0,0)$

So finding the Hessian matrix at $(0,0)$

- $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}[(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)]=\frac{\partial
     f}{\partial x}[8x^3-6xy]=24x^2-6y$
- $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y^2}[(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)]=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}[-3x^2+2y]=2$
- $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x \partial y}[(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)]=\frac{\partial
     f}{\partial x}[8x^3-6xy]=-6x$

$H(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

Finding the eigenvalues for $H(0,0)$:

$\det(H(0,0)-\lambda I)= \begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda & 0 \\
0 & 2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} = \lambda^2-2\lambda$

$\lambda^2-2\lambda=0 \iff \begin{cases} 
      \lambda_1 = 0 \\
      \lambda_2 = 2 
   \end{cases}$

So I can't really tell if $f(x,y)$ has any relative maximum nor minimum or a saddle point, and I don't know how to continue...

**Edit:** I know that this is a [duplicate post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023796/2nd-derivative-test-fail?rq=1), but I don't understand the answer, and the question is 4 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting the linked OP's solution.

For $x^2<\color{red}{y=1.5x^2}<2x^2$:
$$f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)=(1.5x^2-x^2)(1.5x^2-2x^2)<0.$$
For $\color{red}{y=0.5x^2}<x^2$:
$$f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)=(0.5x^2-x^2)(0.5x^2-2x^2)>0.$$
Hence, it is a saddle point.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)=y^2-3x^2y+2x^4=\left(y-\frac32x^2\right)^2-\frac14x^4$$

then it is a saddle point, indeed

- $y-\frac32x^2=0 \implies f(x,y)\le 0$
- $x=0 \implies f(x,y)\ge 0$

Comment: You meant $y-\frac32x^2=0$. Maybe that was the downvoter's (not me) objection.

Comment: Yes of course! Thanks